# flux kustomize build failed - resource with an already registered id

Tags: fluxcd

Here is the folder structure for my flux repo

```
└── clusters
  └── homelab
    ├── default
    │   ├── deployment.yaml
    └── flux-system
        ├── gotk-components.yaml
        ├── gotk-sync.yaml
        └── kustomization.yaml
```

And when I pushed the `deployment.yaml` file and checked the deployment using `flux get kustomizations --watch`

I got the following error;

```
NAME        REVISION            SUSPENDED   READY   MESSAGE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
flux-system main@sha1:58009946  False       False   kustomize build failed: accumulating resources: accumulation err='merging resources from './default/deployment.yaml': may not add resource with an already registered id: Deployment.v1.apps/spring-web.[noNs]': must build at directory: '/tmp/kustomization-308548873/clusters/homelab/default/deployment.yaml': file is not directory
```

I've tried deleting the kustomization using `flux delete kustomization flux-system` but it didn't go anything at it still remains in the output.

Also can't see any deployment in k8s under that name when checking `kubectl get deployments -A`

Answer (score 2):

I once got this error because I tried creating two resources with the same name in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a kustomization.yaml file in the default directory.

```
└── clusters
  └── homelab
    ├── default
    │   ├── deployment.yaml
    │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    └── flux-system
        ├── gotk-components.yaml
        ├── gotk-sync.yaml
        └── kustomization.yaml
```

Inside the kustomization.yaml, we should include the deployment.yaml file, as shown below:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - deployment.yaml
```